# how can Reuse same object in Static Method android

Tags: android, image, static, android-imageview

```html
 private void data() {
        for (int i = indexLeft; i < indexRight; i++) {
//            if (i == indexRight) {
//                i = 0; // reset back to the beginning
//            }
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                doSomething(i, this);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }

    public static void doSomething(int objects, MainActi mainActi) {


        mainActi.handlerTop.setProgress(objects);
        Glide.with(mainActi)
                .load(mainActi.imgFiles.get(objects))
                .into(mainActi.imgFrame);




    }
```

In **static** method I have to create **new imageview** every time when get new image. It takes only last image of arraylist. How can we reuse this view every time to get update all images overtime in Android.
I have to do like when seeker get progress change value imageview change images.

Comment: It's better we know why do you want to create new `ImageView` everytime you get a new image. That approach seems not an effective solution.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: private void data() {
        for (int i = indexLeft; i < indexRight; i++) {
         try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                doSomething(i, this);  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  }   }
 }
  public static void doSomething(int objects, MainActi mainActi) {
     mainActi.handlerTop.setProgress(objects);
        Glide.with(mainActi)
                .load(mainActi.imgFiles.get(objects))
                .into(mainActi.imgFrame);
 }

Answer (score 0):

As per your code it will take the last image only. To avoid this you need to attach the `imageview` to a view hence it will persist.

Comment: how can we do this. can you please describe me.